# EditText moves TextView out of the screen when they keyboard is opening

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I have an EditText on the bottom of my layout und a few TextViews on the top. When I click on the EditText it moves from the bottom above the keyboard which is good. But the TextViews also move up and out of the screen so you can't see them until you close the keyboard again. How can I avoid this but still have my EditText above the keyboard? I'm using a RelativeLayout.
Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ncss.tyfby.Feeling"
android:background="#1baa84">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="I am"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/IamTV"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:gravity="bottom" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/iamAdjective"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
        android:hint="powerful"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:onClick="send"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:text="I am"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iam1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:text="I am"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iam2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iam1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="I am"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iam4"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iam3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="I am"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iam5"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iam4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="I am"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iam3"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iam2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

[image: Screen whithout keyboard][image: Screen with Keyboard (TextView moved out of the screen)]

Comment: share your layout xml please

Comment: @Yannik Pieper- Put your entire view in Scrollview so that you can scroll up and see your content. That's it......

Comment: Is there no option where I can make the TextView stay at the top while the editText moves up? Scrolling is a very bad solution in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may explore `windowSoftInputMode` that you can configure for your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file: [activity | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Perhaps `windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` might be useful for you.

In addition to that you will need to change your layout XML to something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ncss.tyfby.Feeling"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#1baa84">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:text="I am"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iam1"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="I am"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iam2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="I am"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iam4"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="I am"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iam5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="I am"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/iam3"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:text="I am"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/IamTV"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/iamAdjective"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
            android:hint="powerful"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:onClick="send"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when I add adjustResize the editText stays at the bottom of the layout when the keyboard comes up so you can't see it.

Comment: Then you should probably consider doing what @Mohammad Z suggested in his answer, in addition to this, enclose your layout within a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I've done it exactly like you showed me but the TextViews still move above the screen when the keyboard opens.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what exactly is happening?

Comment: I added screenshots to my question

Comment: I copied the whole xml code but there is no difference.

Comment: I just made a sample app and test it, works  perfectly for me. Reconfirm what you are doing.

Comment: Did you changed anything else than just the xml? In the Android Manifest for example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126951/discussion-between-kamran-ahmed-and-yannik-pieper).

Answer (score 0):

You should put your entire layout inside a ScrollView and force that to be above of `my_edit_text`:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/my_edit_text">
```

Comment: Should I replace the RelativeLayout by the ScrollView?

Comment: No just put it inside your `ScrollView`