# EditText In android goes back to the top the layout when typing text

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

When adding an EditText View within a relative layout (contained in a scrollview) upon entering text it takes the user back to the top of the activity, (Snapping to the top of the screen) making the user unable to see what they are typing.

**Replication of the issue**

Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:src="@color/purple_500"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:translationY="800dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**What I have tried so far**

So far I have tried adding  `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" .>` to the android manifest but it made no difference and padding the EditText allthough I cannot find other cases of this happening.

Adding `wrap_content` to `android:layout_height="",` which has not resloved the issue

**Edit**

I needed to contain the Edit Text Within A Linear Layout, Within the Relative Layout, as seen here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316454/edittext-moves-textview-out-of-the-screen-when-they-keyboard-is-opening

Comment: It's probably because your RecyclerView has match_parent instead of wrap_content. Try that

Comment: May I know why you set ImageView's height as 1000dp?

Comment: It's just do demonstrate that the EditText is off screen when typed into @vijay

Comment: Have you considered using a ConstraintLayout instead of a RelativeLayout (which is deprecated)?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the auto scroll to top effect during writing on EditText you can make a subclass of ScrollView and return 0 to the protected method: `computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(Rect rect)`

[computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(android.graphics.Rect))

> Compute the amount to scroll in the Y direction in order to get a
> rectangle completely on the screen (or, if taller than the screen, at
> least the first screen size chunk of it).

Make a subclass of ScrollView and return 0 on that method like below:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(Rect rect) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Xml Usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my.package.name.CustomScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:src="@color/purple_500"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:translationY="800dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</my.package.name.CustomScrollView>
```